# Client Web, try to create a dynamic table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, client

Create a dynamic table in jQuery, I have problem because I send string with dynamic tags, but the Client don't see the table.

```
function recorreTablero(tablero) {
    var tamano = tablero.length;
    var flag = 1;
    var tableroHTML = '<table> <tr>';
    var index = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= tamano; i++) {

      if(i === tamano && flag !== 2){
        break;
      }
      if (i % n_n === 0 && i !== 0) {
        tableroHTML += '</tr> <tr>';
        if(flag !== 2) {
          flag ++;
        } else {
          flag = 1;
          i -= n_n;
        }
      }

      if (flag === 1) {
        if (tablero[i][0].derecha === 'solido') {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="punto"/>';
          index++;
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_horizontal_seleccionada"/>';
          //tableroConsola += index+"----";
        } else if((i + 1) % n_n === 0) {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="punto"/>';
        }else {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="punto"/>';
          index++;
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_horizontal"/>';
          //tirable('#idTab' + index, i, 'r');
        }
        index++;
      } else if (flag === 2) {
        if (tablero[i][0].arriba === 'solido' && tablero[i][0].cerrado !== 'abierta') {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_vertical_seleccionada"/>';
          index++;
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="campo"/>' + tablero[i][0].cerrado +'</td>';
        } else if (tablero[i][0].arriba === 'solido') {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_vertical_seleccionada"/>';
          index++;
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="campo"/>';
        } else if((i + 1) % n_n === 0) {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_vertical"/>';
        } else {
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="linea_vertical"/>';
          index++;
          tableroHTML += '<td id="idTab' + index +'" class="campo"/>';
          //tirable('#idTab' + index, i, 'u');
        }
        index++;
      }
    }
    tableroHTML += '</tr></table>';

    $("#seccion_tablero").html(tableroHTML);
  }
```